# Has Frama-C been verified?

Tags: frama-c, formal-verification

I am curious as to whether Frama-C has been formally verified using Frama-C or another verification framework, since bugs in Frama-C could possibly result in bugs in programs verified by Frama-C going unnoticed.

I understand that the process would be extremely tedious, but given that Frama-C is used in various industries for critical applications like nuclear systems and aviation, I would expect that some organizations would be willing to verify it.

Comment: I am afraid this question doesn't misinterprets the way verification tools are used and requires a broad discussion of formal methods and their purpose. Such questions would better fit [Computer Science Stack Exchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 4):

The first part of your question is extremely easy to answer: Frama-C is written in OCaml, and dedicated to verify programs written in C, so that you can't verify Frama-C in Frama-C.

Regarding the verification of Frama-C through other means, there have been various works dedicated to formalize some analyses, but usually only on a subset of C and ACSL. This often includes the [Coq](https://coq.inria.fr/) proof assistant. A non-exhaustive list of such examples include:

- Paolo Herm's [PhD](https://www.theses.fr/fr/2013PA112006) on the Jessie plug-in
- Jean-Christophe Léchenet's [PhD](https://www.theses.fr/2018SACLC056) on the Slicing plug-in
- Dara Ly's [PhD](https://nikolai-kosmatov.eu/publications/ly_thesis.pdf) on the E-ACSL plug-in
- Lionel Blatter's [articles](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-031-19849-6_28) on the RPP plug-in (and partially WP)

Finally, regarding deployment in industrial domains with stringent constraints (in the form of some certification authority giving some formal -in lawyer's sense rather than mathematical's one- stamp of approval), [Airbus](https://www.erts2020.org/inc/telechargerPdf.php?pdf=ERTS2020_paper_54.pdf) and [Thales](https://nikolai-kosmatov.eu/publications/djoudi_hkkomff_erts_2022.pdf) have published papers on how their use of Frama-C helped them in getting their products certified.